# How to pull branches from remote source

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

How do I fetch back all the branches for my repository on Git?
I tried the following:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:anchetaWern/Zenoir-Online-Classroom.git
git pull git@github.com:anchetaWern/Zenoir-Online-Classroom.git
```

I have 3 branches in that repository but now I only have the master branch. How do I pull back the other 2?

Comment: Are you having troubles working with branches, or with adding a remote origin?  I'm not sure which one is the "root" problem.

Comment: I'm trying to pull from the github repository in such a way that I get all 3 of the branches in that repository since I'm only getting the master branch in the method mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do the 'git remote add origin the-repo' just perform a 'git fetch -a origin' at which point all the branches are there and ready to be checked out.  Here is a typical workflow:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ebg/test/dev5/.git/
$ git remote add origin  /Users/ebg/test/dev1
$ git fetch -a origin
remote: Counting objects: 41, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
remote: Total 41 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (41/41), done.
From /Users/ebg/test/dev1
 * [new branch]      add-on     -> origin/add-on
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
$ git checkout add-on
Branch add-on set up to track remote branch add-on from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'add-on'
```

So, for this example, branch 'add-on' is now in the working directory and 'git checkout master' will get files from the remote 'origin' if needed.

Answer (score 3):

After adding the remote `origin`, you don't have to refer to the url again. That is the point of adding the remote.

You could have done `git pull origin`

Now, if you do `git branch -a` you will see the remote branches ( the 2 that are "missing"). By default only the master is checked out as a local branch.

Just do `git checkout branch_name` to check them out and setup a local branch ( once each)

Answer (score 1):

When I work with branches, this is my typical workflow:

1. push branch to github

   ```
   git push origin newbranch
   ```
2. pull branches on github to another computer

   ```
   git fetch origin
   ```
3. work on branch pulled from github

   ```
   git checkout -b newbranch origin/newbranch
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To checkout myBranch that exists remotely and not a locally - This worked for me:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout <BranchName>
```

Another solution:

I have used fetch followed by checkout ...

```
git fetch <remote> <rbranch>:<lbranch> 
git checkout <lbranch>
```

... where  is the remote branch or source ref and  is the as yet non-existent local branch or destination ref you want to track and which you probably want to name the same as the remote branch or source ref.